# CORS issue when fetching localhost:8080/ from react frontend, to spring-boot backend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc, cors

I am trying to deploy my React app to a GCP server.
I started the react app by `npm start` which started the app at `30.xxx.xx.xxx:3000` , I have made it so that I can access that port over the internet.
I have a spring application running that I started with `mvn spring-boot:run`, and is listening on port 8080

The problem is my react website cannot call backend spring application. for example.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import './pages_styling/menu_items.css';

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/getMenuItems";

const MenuItems = () => {
    const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([]);

    const showMenuItems = async (name) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}`, {method: "GET"});
        const data = await response.json();
    
        // console.log(data);
        setMenuItems(data);
      }

    useEffect(() => {
        showMenuItems();
    }, []);
```

In my spring application I have WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://30.xxx.xx.xxx:3000")
                        .allowedMethods(HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                                HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                                HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                                HttpMethod.DELETE.name())
                        .allowedHeaders(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                                HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I had the same issue I first started testing, which is when I added WebMvcConfigurer, which fixed the issue.
But once I started running it on the servers I am failing to call the localhost:8080
this the error from Mozilla
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at` [`http://localhost:8080/getMenuItems`](http://localhost:8080/getMenuItems)`. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).`

Chrome:

`GET http://localhost:8080/getMenuItems net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`